# how to hide an api key with php and js together

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, api, facebook-access-token

Im making API request from facebook graph api. i would like to hide the id and access token from client side. so i stored the access token on php then i got the data with js. but then i realized that it still shows on the console.log . how can i make it secure ? how to hide the api key? the data still show on the console so im not sure how i can hide thed data. i also have tried .env method but i know i can access from client side only on server side.

```
  let faceIDnum = sns_show_options.facebookID;
let faceID = faceIDnum.toString();
console.log(faceID);
 const businessIDface = faceID ;
```

this is how i did with js.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();


$snspostcount = get_option('post_count_number');
$sns_facebook_id_info = get_option('facebook_page_id' );

$sns_post_count = putenv("SNS_POST_TOTAL=$snspostcount");
$sns_post_count_val = getenv('SNS_POST_TOTAL');

$sns_facebook = putenv("SNS_FACEBOOK_ID=$sns_facebook_id_info");
$sns_facebook_id = getenv('SNS_FACEBOOK_ID');

// $nametag = $_ENV["SKDAI"];
var_dump($sns_post_count_val);

function wp_enqueue_javascript_scripts() {

    wp_register_script( 'javascript-js', get_template_directory_uri() . './js/index.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'javascript-js' );
    wp_localize_script( 'javascript-js', 'sns_show_options', 
    [
     'facebookID'=> getenv('SNS_FACEBOOK_ID')
  
     
    ]
    );
}
```

Comment: This is not possible. You cannot somehow "hide" something from the client side, since you do not have control over the client side. Everything you hand out is usable there.

Comment: just do the api calls from your backend then..